# Get previous 10 row from specific WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im currently working on a project that requires MySql database and im having a hard time constructing the query that i want get.

i want to get the previous 10 rows from the specific WHERE condition on my mysql query.

for example

My where is date='December';

i want the last 10 months to as a result.

Feb,march,april,may,june,july,aug,sept,oct,nov like that.

Another example is.
if i have a 17 strings stored in my database. and in my where clause i specify that WHERE strings='eyt' limit 3

```
Test
one
twi
thre
for
payb
six
seven
eyt
nayn
ten
eleven
twelve
tertin
fortin
fiftin
sixtin
```

the result must be

```
payb
six
seven
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions or answers

Comment: Share what you tried along with sample input and expected output

Comment: order by id desc limit 0,10 or something would work but I don't understand your date condition

Comment: How your DB structure is ?

Comment: What do you mean by `i want to get the previous 10 rows`??? You may ask for last 10 rows with date='December'....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO this is the right syntax:

```
$objStmt = $objDatabase->prepare('SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10');
```

You can change `ASC` to `DESC` in order to get either the first or the last 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (select id from mytable where strings = 'eyt' order by id limit 1) x
  on t.id < x.id
order by t.id desc
limit 3
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ffc4/2

It outputs the rows in descending order, but you can either live with that, or else put that query in a subquery and reverse the order.

---

Re your comment:

`x` in the above query is called a "correlation name" so we can refer to columns of the subquery as if they were columns of a table. It's required when you use a subquery as a table.

I chose the letter `x` arbitrarily. You can use anything you like as a correlation name, following the same rules you would use for any identifier.

You can also optionally define a correlation name for any simple table in the query (like `mytable t` above), so you can refer to columns of that table using a convenient abbreviated name. For example in `t.id < x.id`

Some people use the term "table alias" but the technical term is "correlation name".

Comment: what is the x stands for?